# How to use the default iOS font in an Android React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fonts

I think the default font used in an iOS React Native project is San Francisco. I want to be able to use this font directly in Android as well. Is there a way to directly do this?

Comment: please can you specify which react-native version are you using?
and also are you using Expo-managed workflow or react-native-cli?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this. As of today (2022 Aug), the licence agreement states that SF Pro may be used on "...software products running solely on iOS, iPadOS, macOS or TvOS". (Also I'm not a lawyer)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**React Native just uses the default font family for each platform**. So that's San Francisco on IOS and Roboto for Android.

To Use San Francisco for android you can not directly use it . You have to add fonts in "android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/" and then you can use it.

Comment: I added the fonts in the said folder. But the thing is those fonts are not getting applied. I don't know what's the issue. Went through some issues that others have faced. It mainly involved changing names of the files to lower case. I even tried that. But still it doesn't seem to work. Example: changed the file name of SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf to sfprodisplay_regular.otf, still it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: How you are applying fonts . Did you are using like this fontFamily: "SFUIDisplay-Semibold" in style . You have to add "fontFamily" to text to apply font . Also please do not add extension .

Comment: Yeah, I am using it as {fontFamily: "fontname"}

Answer (score 0):

React Native just uses the default native font family for each platform. So that's San Francisco on IOS and Roboto for Android.

If you want modification in that please follow this blog for complete details.
[Using custom fonts in react native](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78)

Answer (score 0):

After adding fonts in assets folder, you've to build a new APK and then use the font file name as `fontFamily` in react native stylesheet.